# List-View with dynamic columns

Tags: c++, windows, api, listview

I have a List-View with `LVS_REPORT` style, and i'm using the `LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP` style to allow the user to move the columns around.
And the user is going to be able to add/remove columns dynamically. And i'm populating it in `LVN_GETDISPINFO`.

So unless i'm looking at this all wrong, I need to keep track of which columns are visible, and in what order they are.

My current implementation is to have an `enum` of 'column ids' and an array of `ints` for each column, and the value in the array will specify the column position.

Example:

```
enum {FIRSTNAME = 0, LASTNAME, STREET, ADDRESS};

int cols[] = {
      LASTNAME,  // Last Name, this will be displayed in the first column
      FIRSTNAME, // First Name, this will be displayed in the second column
      ADDRESS    // Address, this is displayed in the third column
};
```

And in `LVN_GETDISPINFO`:

```
NMLVDISPINFO *plvdi = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(lParam);

if (cols[plvdi->item.iSubItem] != -1)
{
    GetDataByRowAndColumn(plvdi->item.iItem, cols[plvdi->item.iSubItem]);
}
```

Now the problem is, if a user changes the order of the columns, I haven't found a way to figure out the new order of the columns so I can update my array.

So is there a message sent when the user changes the order of the columns?
I haven't found one on msdn.
Or is my method of doing this completely wrong, and I should approach this differently?

Comment: The listview control should be automatically converting column positions to subitems for you, so just use the subitem to decide what to return. You can use the `LVM_GETCOLUMNORDERARRAY` message if you want to peek at the column order.

Comment: I haven't played with this for a while, but if I recall correctly the subitem index does not change when the columns are reordered by the user.  I think the column index is tracked separately by the list view, so you shouldn't have to worry about it.  My memory could be wrong, though.

Comment: If I use `ListView_InsertColumn` to insert a column with an index that already exists, do the other ones get shifted over, or how does that work?

Comment: Well, that's the way it works with items so I imagine columns would behave the same way.